# Jersey - upload images files - error closing message content input stream

Tags: java, spring, server, jersey

I'm using jersey for my WS, 
this is my WS:

```
     @POST
            @Path("/upload")
            @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8" })
            public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader, 
                    @Context UriInfo info, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    System.out.println("UPLOAD FILE start");
    ...
}
```

sometimes when client (an android mobile application) send request with images to this WS I get this error:

```
<09:56:44 IST 07/03/2018> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101107> <[ServletContext@1357305147[app:Mobile-V1.0.0-EAR module:Mobile-V1.0.0-EAR path:/Mobile spec-version:2.5]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.createWithResolvedBean(HandlerMethod.java:219)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
checkUser start date:Wed Mar 07 09:56:44 IST 2018
LOGINURL=http://localhost:8000
client.target  http://localhost:8000/Entitlement/api/login/customers
customerId=139
source :login/customers/139/entitlements
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error closing message content input stream.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
```

After many attempts sometimes client upload the images successfully but sometimes not. This error appear before the WS is start, the "UPLOAD FILE start" line not prints to logs.

Here is a link for site that help me create this WS:
[jersey multi files upload](https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jax-rs-jersey-ajax-multi-file-upload-example/)

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.